# Random search results

Tags: ee2, search

We have an EE 2.7.2 installation with a search feature produces random results.  Sometimes, a keyword that definitely exists on the site returns results when entered into the search box, but other times, it will produce a "no results found".  Same keyword, same browser, different results.

Sometimes, if I search for the keyword four or five times, a result is eventually displayed.  Other times, a keyword produces instant results from the first search.  There's no rhyme or reason for the results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the keywords you're searching for present in the title field or custom fields? Can you also copy in your search form code so we can see if there are any params there which may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our resolution to this question was to switch to the Low Search add-on.

(http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Channel(s) Preferences CP>Admin>Channels (Administrative Preferences) which field is used for search excerpts? And have you checked if the fields are searchable in your custom fields? CP>Admin>Channel Fields